# Grid layout cell

Tags: layout, extjs, grid

Can somebody help me to create the following grid layout (picture)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be implement with [Grouped Header](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/group-header-grid.html)

Comment: Yes I know, but I wan't that the grouped header wouldn't be displayed. Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?